# Nuget con mas de un nivel de dependencias c#

Tags: c#, nuget

Estamos teniendo problemas a la hora de instalar nugets con dependencias cuyas dependencias tienen otras dependencias. Publicamos en un Azure Artifacts nugets con mas de un nivel de depencencias y al instalar dichos nugets solo se instalan las de primer nivel. Por ejemplo:

- Nuget **A** tiene una dependencia con nuget **B**.
- Nuget **B** tiene una dependencia con Nuget **C**.

**A**, **B** y **C** son nugets publicados en nuestro Azure Artifacts.

Según este escenario, cuando instalamos el nuget **A** en cualquier solución se nos instala automáticamente su dependencia **B** (listada como tal), sin embargo el nuget **C** no llega a instalarse (a pesar de que es necesario para que **B** funcione). ¿Hay alguna forma de que al instalar **A** no solo se instalen sus dependencias sino que también se instalen las dependencias de las dependencias?

Todos estos nugets se publican y pushean en nuestro artifacts a través de un pipeline como el siguiente:

```
parameters:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  nugetFeed: '[Our_GUID_Feed]'
  solution: ''
  project: ''
  BuildConfiguration: ''


jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: '${{ parameters.vmImage }}'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Restore packages'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '${{ parameters.solution }}'
        vstsFeed: '${{ parameters.nugetFeed }}'
      env:
          System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)

        
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Dotnet Build Project'
      inputs:
        arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.BuildConfiguration }} /p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber) /p:Optimize=false --no-restore' 
        projects: '${{ parameters.project }}'
        versioningScheme: byBuildNumber

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Dotnet Package Project' 
      inputs: 
        command: pack
        packagesToPack: '${{ parameters.project }}'
        buildProperties: Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 
      displayName: 'Dotnet Push Project' 
      inputs: 
        command: push 
        nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
        publishVstsFeed: '${{ parameters.nugetFeed }}'
```